# Show/hide loop js issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a little help with the JS  for this show/hide function

Essentially in the site there is PHP loop which echos out the HTML code below X-number of times.

I needed some JS to allow me to target each individual instance with a show/hide function, unfortunately my knowledge of JavaScript is low - I had some assistance from a developer with the code below but I seem to have gone wrong somewhere down the line as the console returns this error message "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

Any insight or help into this will be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance

**The HTML**

```
<span class="contentShow" >Dropdown Text Here...</span>
<a id="prod_more_trigger" ><span>More...</span></a>
```

**The JS**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {

            var i = 0;
            $(document).find('span.contentShow').each(function() {
                $(this).attr('data-id', i++);

                $('span.contentShow').hide();

            });

            i = 0;
            $(document).find('a.prod_more_trigger').each(function() {
                $(this).attr('data-id', i++);
                $(this).click(function() {

                var $span = $(document).find('span.content[data-id="' + $(this).attr('data-id) + "]');


                $('span.contentShow').toggle('fast');


                });
            });


        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing couple of quotes in this line below

```
   find('span.content[data-id="' + $(this).attr('data-id) + "]');
```

supposed to be

```
   find('span.content[data-id="' + $(this).attr('data-id') + '"]');
                                                        ^    ^
                                                        |    |
                                          Missing the closing quote
```

Also your anchor looks like this

```
<a id="prod_more_trigger">
```

Supposed to be

```
<a class="prod_more_trigger">
```

Since you are using class selector in your `JS`

You need not create a local variable `i` to assign a value. `$.each` passes a index. And you do not need to nest the event handler inside the `$.each` loop

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Cache your selectors when using multiple times
    var $content = $('span.contentShow'),
        $trigger = $('a.prod_more_trigger');
    $content.each(function (i) {
        $(this).attr('data-id', i);
    });
    // This can be outside the loop
    $content.hide();

    $trigger.each(function (i) {
        $(this).attr('data-id', i);
    });

    $trigger.click(function () {
        var $span = $('span.content[data-id="' + $(this).attr('data-id') + '"]');
        $content.toggle('fast');
    });
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/nJpaZ/1/)**

Comment: Great, thanks! - if I wanted to only apply the show/hide function to the particular instance that is being clicked would I need to assign specific IDs to each incrementally?

Comment: Glad to have helped.. :) Sure that should do

Answer (score 0):

On your code you specified `prod_more_trigger` as id, it should be class

**HTML**

```
<span class="contentShow" >Dropdown Text Here...</span>
<a class="prod_more_trigger" ><span>More...</span></a>
```

Comment: Thank you! wish I noticed this (It was a late night ha)